# Css File not loading in CI

Tags: css, codeigniter, loading

I am modifying a theme in CI but one of the theme css is not loading.

CSS file included in theme like:

```
<link id="bs-css" href="css/bootstrap-cerulean.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I have included the same file as:

```
<link  href="<?php echo base_url();?>library/css/bootstrap-cerulean.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

if I am not writing `id="bs-css"`
the CSS files are not loading.

Thanks in advance

Comment: use `base_url()` before your `css` path..

Comment: you are saying file is loading using this <link id="bs-css" href="css/bootstrap-cerulean.min.css" rel="stylesheet">  but you want to include file without id="bs-css"

Answer (score 0):

use

```
      <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>library/css/bootstrap-cerulean.min.css"
 rel="stylesheet" >
```

it works only when **library** is a folder in first level. 
ie ,

-application

-**`library`**

-system

Hope it helps

Comment: Library folder is at first level only

Answer (score 0):

in your head

```
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "<?php echo base_url('library/css/bootstrap-cerulean.min.css');?>">
```

Comment: in which  file and where you try?

Comment: and where you put your css file ?